# webkit-scrollbar leaves trail line in iOS safari

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have added a `webkit-scrollbar` to my Jekyll blog. I am using this code in my css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
    height: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(253,206,147,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

It works great but on iOS Safari there appears to be a very thin line left behind the scroll bar. Here is the original view:

[image]

Now look to the left of the scroll bar, and you can see a very thin line the same width as the actual scroll bar:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it? Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Do you have this online somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing more than a rendering artifact from your:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
```

Shadow enabled:

[image]

Shadow disabled:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the artifact or is the only thing I can do is disable the shadow?

Comment: I'd just turn it off. Just in my opinion, it looks better anyway. This is akin to a glitch, you can try playing around with other values and see if you can make it un-glitch itself. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Great spot!